# What functions do registry cleaner programs perform and has Microsoft stated a recommendation on their use?

Tags: windows, maintenance

My IT folks tell me programs like CC Cleaner, AVG, Advanced System Care and other one-click and registry cleaner programs aren't worth using. They say that they can do more harm than good.

I agree that user behavior is the first step to a well-running PC (i.e., not clicking on unknown things), and that the second step is doing some Windows customization (like deleting startup items that aren't needed). But **does a registry cleaner perform an essential function or improve performance under any specific conditions?**

I've just fallen into the habit of using these all-in-one cleaners to make my PC maintenance job easier. I'm a statistician, casual programmer, and PC hobbyist, so I don't mind learning some more manual tips and tricks, but maintaining 2-3 machines for myself plus my wife's machines can be come a chore.

**Also, are there specific problems these programs fix that can be checked and fixed manually in a practical way without using such a program?**

Comment: I think this is more of an opinion based answer really.  Some say they work, some say they don't.  I've "noticed" a significant difference at times when using registry cleaners, but saying "I've noticed" isn't really proof that anything happened.  Maybe it's just the placebo effect and really it's exactly the same.  Not sure you'll get an answer here as it's more opinion based and those aren't usually acceptable here, but if you do, I'd be interested in knowing if anyone has done any actual testing and has real results.

Comment: `CCleaner` is helpful just not as a register cleaning tool despite its ability to "fix" Windows registry problems.  AVG has nothing to do with fixing registry problems, and ASC is a bunch of rubbish.

Comment: I have found CCleaner to clear up gigs of used space on my hard drive, I use that one occasionally for that purpose

Comment: AT Ramhound That is extremely unhelpful to say Ccleaner is helpful and then state how it isn't helpful. It's good to say how you think it isn't helpful but it'd be better to also say how it is helpful if you're going to say it is helpful, which you did. Also since you are saying something is helpful as something, e.g. as a registry cleaner, it's worth saying why you think it's unhelpful as a registry cleaner, what if anything you think is better. I have seen CCleaner speed a computer up and possibly partly from cleaning the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your IT folks, avoid those programs like the plague itself.

If they work you get a minor disk space back and possibly a barely noticeable performance gain. Every now and then they break things though and no minor gain is worth breakage. Instead, just backup and reinstall your desktop every 1 year or so.

A good choice of antivirus software can be good though. If you are careful and keep up on security updates you may not even need it running in the background and can just use it for manual scans on things you download.

Comment: When you say every now and then they break things, can you give an example of what you call a break?

Comment: They can remove things from the registry which is needed for windows or (more commonly) programs need to run. They aren't supposed to remove things that are needed but they are using educated guesses as to what is no longer being used. Eventually it will choose wrongly.

Comment: As I say, can you give a specific example. Because some of these things are going to be very very easy to fix and some may not be. If you can get benefits from it a lot, then from time to time an easy to fix break that takes 3 minutes to fix(if that's what you are describing), then so what. If it takes 2 hours to fix then that's an issue. I'd be interested in a specific example - which program, and what problem specifically did it cause.

Comment: No, I cant give you a specific example other then i tried a few of theese a couple of years back and one of them messed up windows in such a way that it needed a reinstall. But its not like I remember which one it was. But it was enough for me to avoid them, the performance gain is not worth the risk.

Comment: If you tried a few of these and one of them broke things, but you don't even recall which program it was that broke them.. and you didn't have that experience with the others, then it's a bit of a generalization to talk about them breaking things every now and then, that said the question is a bit general too.  And it sounds like you had the one experience with one of them and then avoided them completely. It's not much experience with them. If there's an incompatibility that caused a problem like that you should've made a post about it somewhere to report it.

Comment: Essentially, there's no way that a registry cleaning utlity can know what's supposed to be in a particular machine's registry -- and indeed, registry sittings just sitting there doing nothing -- literally don't do anything except take up one or two bytes of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

This questions really depends on what you are trying to accomplish and how prepared you are in case something goes wrong. I've been using these utilities for years on my personal machines as well as my parent's machines. CCleaner is a good tool to use to free up disk space and delete outdated/orphaned registry entries. However, it can and will delete files and registry entries that you may need for other programs unintentionally. It is important to backup your registry before performing these operations. Also I would reccomend you use a reputable file or OS imaging solution in case the operations have unexpected results. It is good practice to go through the settings in these applications and modify them to your preference before running them to avoid some of these issues. CCleaner does allow you to select which regitry entries to delete so take your time and go through them. I haven't had much luck with the other utilities you've mentioned so I would advise against their use. It's a good idea to try them all out and see what works best for your situation though but be sure to backup things first.